# why I need " override def toString(): String = x.toString" in the following code and how is work?

Tags: scala

```
/* scala code;
   by this code I am going to sum two integers with one class that
   has an one input as a parameter
*/

object Rationals {
  def main (args : Array[String]) {
    var p  = new rational(1)
    var pp = new rational(2)
    println(p.add(pp)) // **I expect 3 in result**
  }
}

/*
 * the class rational with 2 calls in main function,
 * sums the parameters of two calls
 */ 

class rational(x: Int) {
  def n = x

  def add (that: rational) = new rational(n + that.n) 

  override def toString(): String = x.toString  /* this line is my question */

  /*
   * n most to be equals to 1
   * and than.n most be equals to 2 =====> n+ than.n = 1+ 2 = 3
   */                        
}
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: I formatted it - my eyes were bleeding too much

Answer (score 0):

An equal sign is missing : `def add (that : rational) =`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to implement this, with operator overloading and implicits (and string interpolation),

```
case class Rational (i: Int) {
  def +(that: Rational) = Rational(i+that.i)
}

object Rationals extends App {
  implicit def int2Rational (i: Int) = Rational(i)

  val r1 = Rational(1)
  val r2 = r1 + 3

  println(s"$r1+3=$r2")
}
```

Then

```
scala> Rationals.main(Array())
Rational(1)+3=Rational(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to override toString:

```
class rational(x: Int) {
  def n = x

  def add(that: rational) =
    new rational(n + that.n)

  override def toString(): String = x.toString
}
```

Comment: thanks, but what is the tak of "override def toString(): String = x.toString" in this code?

Comment: p.add(pp) in your println() call invokes toString method on the object you pass to it, which in this case is toString of the implicit base class. Default toString returns "ClassName" + "@" + "hexHashCode". So you need to override default implementation to see what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things are wrong here

**1. Badly-formatted code**

How can you expect to read your own code?  The indentation was all over the place and you haven't been consistent with e.g. spacing around a `:`.  I had to reformat the code in the question before I could see what was going on.

**2. Using `var` where a `val` would be more appropriate:**

```
var p  = new rational(1)
var pp = new rational(2)
println(p.add(pp)) // **I expect 3 in result**
```

Why `var`?  You never mutate `p` and `pp`

**3. Re-exposing a constructor value via a `def`**

```
class rational(x: Int) {
  def n = x
  ...
}
```

This gains nothing, if you want the value to be public then use a case class, or flag it as a `val` in the class signature:

```
class rational(val n: Int) {
  ...
}
```

**4. As a class name, `rational` should really begin with an uppercase letter**

```
class Rational(...
```

**As for the original question...**

`toString` must be declared as `override` because it's defined as a concrete (i.e. not abstract) method in the `Object` class, and **all** classes on the JVM inherit from `Object`.

In Scala, whenever you're redefining (overriding) a method from a supertype - as opposed to implementing an `abstract` method - you **must** use the `override` keyword.  This is to prevent you from *accidentally* redefining something that's already a mmember of your class via inheritance.

In this case, it's being overridden so that the `String` representation of a `Rational` is the contained number.  The default implementation of `toString` just gives you a JVM-supplied hash code, which is rarely useful.